# Customize AWS Identity Providers iOS Permission Message

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I want to implement Google authentication with AWS Cognito identity providers. Authentication itself works but I want to change iOS permission alert that shows when trying to sign in with Google. It says: MyApp wants to use "amazoncognito.com" to sign in. Is it possible to change amazoncognito.com in the alert message to google.com? Because I think that amazoncognito.com might be confusing to the user.

I am using Amplify Flutter, and Google authentication is launched as mentioned in [docs](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/social_signin_web_ui/q/platform/flutter#launch-social-web-ui-sign-in).

```dart
try {
    var res = await Amplify.Auth.signInWithWebUI(provider: AuthProvider.google);
} on AmplifyException catch (e) {
    print(e.message);
}
```

This code shows the permission dialog on iOS.

If it is not possible to do this, then what is an alternative to implement Google authentication with AWS in Flutter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USE .preferPrivateSession() TO HIDE THE ALERT POPUP

Prefer private session during signIn

```
Amplify.Auth.signInWithWebUI(presentationAnchor: self.view.window!, 
                             options: .preferPrivateSession()) { ... }
```